# Copy animation from empty in viewport to mask

Tags: animation, masking

I want to move a mask along a path. I have an empty in the viewport that already follows the path I want. Is there anyway to group/pair a mask to the empty from the viewport?

My project:
I have an image with a shape that has an outline. I want use the mask to slide it along the outline. The outline is curved so I'm using a bezier curve for that.
In the viewport I have created a path that matches the outline. I already have an empty that moves along the path in the way I want. All that is left to do is to pair the mask to the empty from the viewport.

Is that even possible? If not, what else could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check out canvas and canvas paint modifiers.
With it you can use an object to paint over other objects, with even various options, ea you could have paint that slowly evaporates. It can operate in texture space (driving material shaders), or with it alter mesh verticles.

It be easy to make an object and set the parent to the empty you already have